# Symbol ' | ' in probability

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I am with doubt in the following exercise: the random variable Y has a Poisson density with parameters lambda = 2. Get: P(Y=1 | Y < 3). The basic text that li does not explain what is meant by the symbol ' | ' in the range and do not encounter in another text book. My question is what is the symbol ' | ' in the interval. How to solve?

Comment: This is not interval notation, it's conditional probability notation.

Comment: I had a vague idea that it would be conditional probability, but was playing so rough, since the other exercises asked, for example, P(2 <= Y < 4), believed that it would be an interval of probability, but didn't know to solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is known as a [conditional probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability). $P(A|B)$ means the probability of $A$ occurring given that $B$ is true. In your example
$$P(Y = 1 | Y < 3)$$
means the probability that $Y = 1$ if it is given that $Y < 3$.

Comment: I solved: P (Y = 1 | Y < 3) = 0.40

Comment: That seems to be correct.